# Phone call receive tune

Tags: android

Can I set a tune like notification in my phone when I receive a call like a call receive indicator?
Im using google pixel 3.
Its like my phone is ringing I receive and the sound plays the moment receive or disconnect call

I search the setting.
Cant find any solution in youtube

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the phone. For me, I can change the tune in the settings (`settings -> sound, vibration`). You can also have a tune on your own: copy a soundfile of the format `.ogg` in the folder `/Ringtones/` and choose it in the settings as mentioned.